# SystemParametersInfo behaves differently on Vista and XP

Tags: winapi, windows-vista, windows-xp, incompatibility

I am trying to find the default system font size using `SystemParametersInfo()` with `SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS`.

While on Vista the `LOGFONT` structures inside the returned `NONCLIENTMETRICS` actually have the correct font height in `lfHeight`, when I run the exact same app on XP, `lfHeight` (and `lfWidth`) are always zero.

Why is that so, and what is the correct way to retrieve the font size on both systems?

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting `cbSize` member of `NONCLIENTMETRICS` to `sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS)`?
According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724506%28VS.85%29.aspx), you'll need a runtime system version check, and subtract the size of the `iPaddedBorderWidth` when running under Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the 100% correct answer, but according to MSDN the value of zero has a special meaning for both lfHeight and lfWidth:

this is taken from MSDN, [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145037(VS.85).aspx) Windows GDI, "LOGFONT"

**lfHeight** - if 0 - The font mapper uses a default height value when it searches for a match.

**lfWidth** - If lfWidth is zero, the aspect ratio of the device is matched against the digitization aspect ratio of the available fonts to find the closest match, determined by the absolute value of the difference.